# jquery appending instead of an alert message

Tags: jquery, forms, hide, prepend

I wan to display a message into a div rather than alert it, then hide it on `click/blur` 
The alert is popping up due to an error of typing. I need to display a message into a div and not an alert.

**Something like:**

```
$('form.form-calculator input').on('change click', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 0) {
            var div = $("#AlertMessage");
            div = $("<div id='AlertMessage' onclick='$(this).hide();'></div>");
            $("body").prepend(div);
            this.value=0;
        }
        calc_total();
    });
```

**With the Alert**

```
 $(function () {
       $('.form input').on('change click focus', function () {
          if ($(this).val() == 0) {
            alert('HELLO');
            this.value = 0;
          }
          calc_total();
       });
    });
```

Comment: that sounds like a great goal to have.

Comment: its very unclear what you are trying to do.. this is my best guess based on what you have (although it doesnt make much sense to me)  http://jsfiddle.net/ccnch/

Comment: @smerny thanks but how can I stop the loop?

Comment: what loop? you have not indicated specifically what you want and what you don't want.

Comment: The alert is popping up due to an error of typing. I need to display a message into a div and not an alert.

Comment: what is the error based on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $('.form input').on('focusout', function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 0) {
            showError('Hello');
        } else {
            $("#AlertMessage").remove();
        }
        calc_total();
    });

    function showError(text) {
        $("#AlertMessage").remove();
        $('<div/>', {
            id: 'AlertMessage',
            text: "Alert! It can't be 0"
        }).prependTo('body');
        // Close on click
        $('body').delegate('#AlertMessage', 'click', function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: it should be integrated to my code. $('.form input').on('change click focus', function () {
          if ($(this).val() == 0) {
            alert('HELLO');
            this.value = 0;
          }
          calc_total();
       });

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both pieces of your code work (since you didn't ask to troubleshoot those), you can just combine those into one like this:

```
 $(function () {
       $('.form input').on('change click focus', function () {
          if ($(this).val() == 0) {
            div = $("<div id='AlertMessage' onclick='$(this).hide();'>HELLO</div>");
            $("body").prepend(div);
            this.value = 0;
          }
          calc_total();
       });
    });
```